# how to log usage of files in cache - proxy_cache_path

Tags: nginx, logging

I have cache set for accessing to images

```
proxy_cache_path /cache/images-cache/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=media:1m inactive=365d max_size=500m;
```

also I have nginx set

```
server {
  server_name localhost;
  listen 80;
  location ~ "^/(?<id>.+)/(?<width>)/(?<height>)/(?<image>.+)$" {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
    proxy_cache media;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 365d;
    proxy_cache_key $width-$height-$image;
  }
```

How can I set logging so it shows which images are fetched from cache?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a response header

```
add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status always;
```

This will enable you to check if the URL was hit or not.
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

You can also use this variable `$upstream_cache_status` in your logs if you want to generate metrics or persist them in the logs.

Follow the example here
https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/upstream-cache-status-in-access-log/
and add/remove other variables at your convenience.